# How to add dyno in heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

In the present, I am running 2 dynos in my heroku app.

[image: mydyno]

I want to add one more dyno. `worker: python manage.py runworker`

What should I do to add dyno?

==========================================================

edit)

I modified procfile and three dynos are made.
However 1 dyno must be charged. How can I add charged dyno??

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you create the first one? these are all in your Procfile

Comment: Please see above question again. I attach one dyno. However I want to attached dyno to be charged. How can I do that?

Comment: charged as in? If you have 3 then yes, you need to upgrade to Hobby dyno types

Comment: oh, thank you. I got it

Comment: ok good to hear, cheers